Synchronous Unison Algorithm to a CNF formula
How can I transform the Synchronous Unison Algorithm into a CNF formula.
If I have the following Synchronous Unison Algorithm:
Inputs:
p.N: the set of p's neighbors
m: an integer such that m>= max{2, 2*D-1}
Variable:
p.clock in {0, .., m-1}: the clock of p
Macro:
NewClockValue(p) = (min{p.clock} U {q.clock: q appartient à p.N (voisins de p) } +1) mod(m)
Action:
Incr :: p.clock != NewClockValue(p) then p.clock = NewClockValue(p)
